# How do I compare date values?

Tags: date, advanced-conditionals, comparison

I would like to create a conditional based on the value of a date field compared to today's date.

In English it would be: if Expiration Date is less than today's date set class to "expired"

Here is how I tried it in EE:

```
{if "{business_expire_date}" < "{current_time}"}class="expired"{/if}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as desired. What is the correct way to write this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dates need to be formatted properly first to compare them. Something like this:

```
{if {business_expire_date format="%U"} < {current_time format="%U"}}class="expired"{/if}
```

You may need to change the comparison operator `<` to get desired results.